# How to root to the current user's show view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I root to the current user's show view in a Rails app?

I want to do something like

```
authenticated :user do
    root :to => "users#show"
end
```

but how do I pass the current user's ID into this?

Thanks

Comment: Surely there is a sexier way to do this in Rails 4+ than what is suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following worked for me.

In routes.rb:

```
root to: 'users#current_user_home'
```

In users_controller.rb:

```
def current_user_home
  redirect_to current_user
end
```

Answer (score 8):

I did a `before_filter` where I check if `request.path == root_path` and if so I redirect to the path that should be user-specific root. The root_path set in `routes.rb` is not user-specific root for any user so there is no infinite redirection. Just do `flash.keep` to make your flash messages survive the redirection.

**EDIT:**
Reading Q&A and comments, trying to understand what you already has, and what you still need. Did you succeed to setup routing to get `show` action rendered without the `:id` in the URL? If so maybe you need something like this in your controller `show` action:

```
if params[:id].nil? # if there is no user id in params, show current one
    @user = current_user
else # if there is the user id in params just use it, 
     # maybe get 'authorization failed'
    @user = User.find params[:id]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it always the 'current' user or any arbitrary user?

If it is the current user, just direct them all to the same page (without specifying the ID) and in the controller action get the current user (from session etc) and pass it through to the view.

Comment: Hi Michael, I see what you're saying, but I think I am confusing myself as my situation is a little more complex. Grateful if you are able to help me think this through. The root for the current_user should be users/show with the current user's ID. Users should only be able to see their own show view, and no one elses. In this case I could modify the show controller to `@user = current_user`. BUT, I also have an admin model, and admins can view all users' show views. What is the best way to handle this? With a conditional in the show controller, or another approach? Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Current user's ID should not be in url, that should be store in session. So you don't need pass it to the route.

***Edit:***
After reading your comment, I think you could define another action like `profile` for show the current user 's view.

Or at your `users/show` action, add some code like:

```
if current_user.is_admin?
    @user = User.find params[:id]
else
    @user = current_user
end
```

Comment: thanks xdazz, I understand what you mean, but I'm still having trouble displaying the show view. See my comment to MIchael below for a bit more detail. Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Thanks xdazz, I had considered your second solution. But in my situation the current user can see links to other users profiles. Currently if they click those links they receive an authorization error. If I set @user=current_user, then clicking links to other users would root to the current users profile, which would be strange. A profile action might work, though I was hoping there would be a simpler way. I will give it a try.